# CSS: How can I stop the horizontal navigation links from shiningthrough the floating cart when it's accordioned down?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at http://www.StringOfJewels.com

There is a slide show running on the home page. It works by using JavaScript to increment the z-index of the containing DIVs that each slide is in, so if somebody lingers on the homepage for a long time, the slides can climb over the fly-downs from the horizontal product navigation bar and the floating cart when displayed. To deal with this, I arbitrarily set the UL that forms the product nav bar to z-index of 20000000 (20 million). Yeah, probably excessive, but why take chances? I set the ".smb-fc .yui-panel" container

```
<div id="yfc_fc-panel" class="yui-module yui-overlay 
yui-panel" style="visibility: inherit; width: 324.155px;">
```

for the rolled down floating cart (Click "Your shopping basket" to unfurl the floating cart) to a z-index of 21000000. But the links in the horizontal navigation bar shine right through the floating cart when it's displayed.

How can I get the floating cart to accordion down OVER the navigation menu? I can't add local styles because the floating cart is written by JavaScript on a server I do not have access to. (It's a Yahoo! store). All I can do is tweak the CSS of the floating cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<div>` that you set to have the 210000000 z-index is inside a div (`.smb-fc`) that has a z-index of 9999.  You need the parent to have a higher z-index than the navigation.
Doesn't matter how high the child z-index goes, it's parent is still sat behind the navigation.

So...

```
.smb-fc {
  z-index: 21000000;
  left: 595px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yahoo! never makes things easy. That class doesn't even display in the editor where I was troubleshooting it. But I found an even simpler solution. The UL the top nav is generated in sits above the slides anyway. It didn't need to be on a high z-index. I dropped it to the floor and only jacked up the nexted ULs within it that form the flydowns. When the F-cart is deployed, the Hover pseudo class never gets triggered because the horizontal nav is now safely below the floating cart.

Comment: Yeah I've found working with YUI in the past quite hard work.  Glad you solved it.